# Filter Active Record by relation but not the relation itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to filter a model with a has_many relation by a value of it's relation.

This is easily achievable by using `Foo.include(:bars).where(bars: { foobar: 2 })`.

If we had an object like this in our database:

```
{
  id: 1,
  bars: [
    { id: 4, foobar: 1 },
    { id: 5, foobar: 2 }
  ]
}
```

This query would only return this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  bars: [
    { id: 5, foobar: 2 }
  ]
}
```

I would like to still filter my records by this relation, but receive all records in the relation.

I was able to achieve this by using something like: `Foo.include(:bars).joins('LEFT JOIN bars AS filtered_bars ON filtered_bars.foo_id = foos.id').where(filtered_bars: { foobar: 2 })` but this does not look very pretty.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the magic of `includes` in action - since you are using `bar` in where, it decides to use a left join and will not preload anything else. You have to explicitly join and prelaod the association here:

```
Foo.joins(:bars).where(bars: {foobar: 2}).uniq.preload(:bars)
```

Some time ago I made a talk on those magic methods, you can find it here: https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/6731-activerecord-vs-n-1